# How to maintain connected state for pusher if not logged in to pusher.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, pusher

I have a ruby on rails app where I need to show notifications for the logged in user about a process completion and I'm using `pusher` gem for the same. I'm in development environment. `Rails 3.2.16` and `Ruby 2.0.0-p247`

## My question:

Without being logged in to the Pusher account, how you could get the message to the client side? I mean if I'm not logged in to the pusher account using my registered email-id and password, I'm not getting the message since the connection is not active. How can we do that?

I have set up a `pusher.rb` file inside `config/initializers`, set it up with the `app_id`, `app_key` and `app_secret` and `url` for it and tested it using the client side code provided by pusher. But, when I logged out from the pusher account, the messages could not be received at all. I need to get messages even if I've been logged out from pusher account.

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="http://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.log = function(message) {
      if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        window.console.log(message);
      }
    };

    var pusher = new Pusher('app_key'); (I have given the correct app_key in my app)
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
    channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
      alert(data.message);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

**config/initilaizers/pusher.rb**

```
require 'pusher'

Pusher.app_id = 'app_id' #I've provided the correct app_id
Pusher.key = 'app_key' #I've provided the correct app_key
Pusher.secret = 'app_secret' #I've provided the correct app_secret
Pusher.url = "http://app_key:app_secret@api.pusherapp.com/apps/app_id"
Pusher.logger = Rails.logger
```

Then from my **Sidekiq worker job**, I've pushed a message to the test channel as below:

```
Pusher['test_channel'].trigger('my_event', {
  message: 'Import process completed!!'
})
```

It works and I'm getting alert only when I'm logged in to https://app.pusher.com, and it works when we could see the connection state as `Connected` inside our pusher account GUI and it is shown as below.

```
This page includes the JavaScript below. Connection state: Connected
```

Also, if change the name `test_channel` to `my_channel`, it is not working.

Please help :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to be logged in.  As long as your pusher server-side code is sending to the correct client-side channel and your key and secret are correct it should work.  Please post your server and client-side code if this is the case

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the problem.  What you're describing seems very strange.  I don't understand why your being logged in or not would affect this.  My only advice is to contact support :(

Comment: @Rich Peck: Can you help me in this please as you have suggested to use `Pusher` earlier as an answer to one of my question.